# get control properties VB6

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to change some logic in VB6 code, and I need to get control property by property name. Something similar to Access **control.properties** property.

```
Dim propertyName as string 
propertyName ="Visible"
Me.Controls("mnuRepots").Properties(propertyName)="True"
```

But my VB6 says **Object doesn't support this property or method**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To execute a method or set or get a property based on a dynamic name, you can use the [`CallByName` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262682%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), like this:

```
CallByName mnuReports, "Visible", vbLet, True
```

Note that there's almost always a better approach to calling different code in different cases by using [polymorphism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241891%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) or a simpler Select Case statement. Loading code dynamically can make code much harder to read, and (if you're ever taking any input from an untrusted source) an easy place to screw up and allow people to call methods that aren't the ones you intended them to call, leading to security vulnerabilities.